# one Button With Multiple Actions Using StoryBoard in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have three buttons with different actions.Now I don't want to create three IBAction to my buttons.In single IBAction Method can i write the actions for those three buttons.

I am new to Xcode,Can anyone help me to do this...

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: simply connect the multiple events to one `IBAction` handler – or it works vica-verse, connecting multiple `IBAction` handlers for one event. where have you been stuck to do this procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

in . h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *yourbutton;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize yourbutton;

 - (IBAction)yourClicked:(id)sender {

             UIButton *resultebutton= (UIButton*)sender;
              NSString *buttontitle=resultButton.currentTitle;

                    if ([buttontitle isEqual:@"firstBtitle"]) {
                        // perform your 1st button action 
                          //call your method

                    }
                    else if ([buttontitle isEqual:@"secondBtitle"]) {
                        // perform your 2nd button action 


                    }
                    else if ([buttontitle isEqual:@"thirdBtitle"]) {
                        // perform your 3rd button action

                    }
}
```

Comment: Please update me where you are struggling .its working for me

Answer (score 1):

Assign tag for buttons, and in IBAction method, check Button tag and do action, according to tag of button.

Comment: If i do like that it is always checking the first button tag only.It is not checking the second button

Comment: write down in if else if condition and give different tag id.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me, if I get you wrong:

You have three buttons and you want them to trigger the same IBAction. The IBAction itself decides what to do based on which button calls it.

This sounds to me like a perfect example for the "sender" parameter.

Create something like this:

```
- (IBAction)doSomeAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isEqual:self.buttonOne]) {
        NSLog(@"ButtonOne");
    } else if ([sender isEqual:self.buttonTwo]) {
        NSLog(@"ButtonTwo");
    } else if ([sender isEqual:self.buttonThree]) {
        NSLog(@"ButtonThree");
    }
}
```

With the sender you can identify the button, which calls this method. This way, you can avoid handle tags which can be very annoying to use.

Make sure you connect all three buttons to this action - take a look at the connections inspector. This is very important and a common source for errors. If you remove any connection to an outlet or an IBAction, also check, if this connection ist remove in the Storyboard-object. 
If everything is in place just compare the sender with the outlets of the buttons.

Comment: I did like that only but the app was crashed.

Comment: Did a little update to my post. But it could be helpful, to see the crash message

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Assign your all three buttons different tag in storyboard/XIB,
For ex. firstButton with tag=1, secondButton with tag=2 and thirdButton with tag=3

Step 2:
Define your method like this and bind all your buttons with this method

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag==1) {
        NSLog(@"First Button");
    } else if (sender.tag==2) {
        NSLog(@"Second Button");
    } else if (sender.tag==3) {
        NSLog(@"Third Button");
    }
}
```

And your work is done.

Comment: @Sport "I have three buttons with different actions" is mentioned in the first line of question.

Comment: It is showing error message.."Property tag not found on object of type '_strong id"

Comment: @iworld there is problem with how you linked your buttons, refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19641844/1223897 for that error.