# UIAlertController error 'bounds' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertcontroller

I am trying to create an alert that when brought up will ask the user if they want to select a photo from their library or take a photo. I am working off of a template from the post [UIPopover How do I make a popover with buttons like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744260/uipopover-how-do-i-make-a-popover-with-buttons-like-this). The template is...

```
UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: nil
                                                                          message: nil
                                                                   preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[alertController addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"Take Photo" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // Handle Take Photo here
}]];
[alertController addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"Choose Existing Photo" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // Handle Choose Existing Photo here
}]];

alertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

UIPopoverPresentationController * popover = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
popover.sourceView = sender;
popover.sourceRect = sender.bounds;

[self presentViewController: alertController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

however at `popover.sourceRect = sender.bounds;` xcode gives me an error that states `Property 'bounds' not found on object of type '__strong id'`. What is this error saying and how is this fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely receiving sender as a parameter to this function with type `id`, which stands for a generic object. The compiler has no idea that it has a property named `bounds`, since it could really be any object. To fix this, you need to tell it that `sender` is actually a `UIView *` by casting it.

```
UIView* senderView = (UIView *)sender;
```

Then you can perform the next assignment:

```
popover.sourceView = senderView;
popover.sourceRect = senderView.bounds;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why on the linked post that the person who posted this template would not include this?

Comment: The type may have already been specified in the function argument, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641751/property-tag-not-found-on-object-of-type-strong-id

Answer (score 0):

The problem is WHEN you're configuring your popover.

The UIKit framework doesn't create that `popoverPresentationController` property until the alert controller has begun presentation. It doesn't actually display it until the next display update cycle, so don't worry that it will flash un-configured first.

Configure after presenting the alert controller and you should be fine.